# HTML Form/Database query

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having some trouble with some code I am trying to implement. Any help would be much appreciated.

In a database table I have 2 fields:

1. postcode
2. area

Every postcode is related to an area.

On a HTML form I have an input field. Users enter their postcode into this field.

My question: what is the best/safest/easiest method, when a user has entered their postcode, to assign it it’s area?

For example:

1. User enters their postcode
2. onSubmit the postcode is assigned an area. This can be in a hidden field.

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need the area at this stage? Why put it in a hidden field?

When you store the postcode in a database table there is no need at all to store the area, because it could/should be retrieved with a query.

When you want to store the area in a cookie, lookup the area once and store it.

Or maybe I didn't understand your problem correctly...

Comment: Hey fransre - thanks for your reply.
The area is necessary. The area will be passed to the URL to call the relevant page.
Because there are hundreds of postcodes, I have created 20 'areas'. As mentioned above, every postcode is assigned an area.
I thought a hidden field would be the easiest way to store the area data to be passed to the URL. I could be very wrong...
I hope that is a little clearer. 
Cheers.